# PHP: antiword and uploaded file

Tags: php, ms-word, exec, doc

I'm creating some code that will upload the contents of a word document to a server, extract its text, and insert it into a database.

```
exec("PATH=$PATH:/home1/myserver/bin && antiword " . 
     $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $mycontent);
```

For some bizarre reason, $mycontent is always an empty array. Google wasn't that helpful. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps escape `$PATH` (if you did not define it by yourself). `exec("PATH=\$PATH...` or use single quotes.

Comment: Thank you. Forgot to do that :)

Answer (score 1):

The $PATH in your exec quote is trying to be converted to whatever your PHP $PATH is rather than the BASH $PATH.

You can either escape the $ (`\$`) or use single quotes.

In general, you should be using `escapeshellarg()` or `escapeshellcmd()` to make things a bit safer.  It would have prevented this situation.  Also if you call `exec()` with user inputs, it will help prevent them from escaping your command and calling their own malicious shell commands.

**EDIT**
Actually, you might have issues with your filename/path for some reason.  Just start simple.

Does this work:

```
exec('/home1/myserver/bin/antiword ' . 
          escapeshellarg($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']), $mycontent);
```

If not, what is this:

```
echo '/home1/myserver/bin/antiword ' . 
          escapeshellarg($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
```

You'll have to create a file to test, and substitute it for the file in $_FILES.  But does that work directly from the commandline?

Comment: Used single quotes, and still no luck :(

Comment: Get rid of the path part all together, just put in the full path for whatever you need it for.  If you're using it for antiword then just do this `exec('/home1/myserver/bin/antiword ' . escapeshellarg($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']), $mycontent);`